# i want to make an Memory Game. What is the best way to create the cards

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

So basically I want to make a Memory game with JS, HTML and CSS. I want to be able to click on Cards which then are supposed to flip with an flip animation.
I don't want to create like 20 buttons. Is there a better way of creating cards with CSS animations.
I kind of know how to create the animations.

```css
  .flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px;
  /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}


/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */

.flip-card:click .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* Position the front and back side */

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}


/* Style the back side */

.flip-card-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
```

```html
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="frontpageofCard" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <img src="Backpage" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to use JS to assign random Pictures on the Backpage.

Comment: What exactly is the question? You don't need 20 buttons to flip each card. There is a `selected` property which can be accessed in CSS. Depending on your js framework there are methods with which you can tell which card was clicked. They all execute the same function. And for JS assigning random pictures on the backpage: Show us your code so far. SO is more of a place when you are running into specific bugs and we help fixing the errors.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create cards with JS like this:

```js
var card = "<div class='flip-card'><div class='flip-card-inner'><div class='flip-card-front'><img src='frontpageofCard' alt='Avatar' style='width:300px;height:300px;'></div><div class='flip-card-back'><img src='Backpage' alt='Avatar' style='width:300px;height:300px;'></div></div></div>"

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
 document.querySelector("#container").innerHTML += card
}
```

```css
 .flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px;
  /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}


/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */

.flip-card:click .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* Position the front and back side */

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}


/* Style the back side */

.flip-card-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: @bgt0123 I have edited the answer and have added a working code snippet. You can view it.

Comment: then I get this error: "Memory.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at Memory.js:5".

Comment: @bgt0123 you need to have a div with id **container** in your HTML (as in above example). All the cards will go into this div.

Comment: @bgt0123 Glad that it worked. Kindly upvote the answer/comments so that others can benefit from it, too! 

Answer (score 1):

Just try to use :active pseudo-class instead of :click

```css
  .flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px;
  /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}


/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */

.flip-card:active .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* Position the front and back side */

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}


/* Style the back side */

.flip-card-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="frontpageofCard" alt="Avatar-Front" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <img src="Backpage" alt="Avatar-Back" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```